# How to Kill IEDriver exe process running in background (Selenium webdriver)?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, taskmanager

I'm using selenium webdriver(for Internet Explorer). What it does it basically opens a webpage in internet explorer and does form submitting.

How can I kill internetexplorer.exe running in background Automatically ?

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following code at the end of your test script to close the IE Driver. So there is no need of closing it manually.

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Else open notepad and paste the following code.

```
taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe
```

Save the file as closedriver.bat

Click on this batch file when u want to close the IE Driver.

Comment: Hi, Tried the above code. But it's not working for me. I tried with your try section but it's not helping me out. Can you provide me any other coding level approach?
Thanks

Comment: See the name of the driver process in task manager. It is possible that the name is different

Comment: Typing `taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe` into CMD worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Close browser:

```
try{
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
.. write all the webdriver code here like driver.get, driver.findElement().click() etc. etc.
}
catch(Throwable webDriverException){
  if(webDriverException.getMessage().contains("org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died"){
      // Kill IEDriverServer.exe process
      // Using WebDriver WindowUtils utility 
      WindowsUtils.killByName("IEDriverServer.exe");

      // Or using JavaRunTime
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe")
  }

}
```

See if this helps!!!

Comment: i want your code to execute whenever browser is closed by the user. is there any browser close(X) event in webdriver.

Comment: Yes in webdriver there is close() method available which closes current browser window. In order to close all the browser windows opened by webdriver, use quit() method. Use the above code after writing close()/quit() method. Edited my earlier response a bit.

Comment: if i use close() or quit() method then it automatically closes the window. But i want user to close the browser himself by pressing browser close(X) button.

Comment: so what i want is if(browser close by user by pressing cross(X) button) then kill iedriverserver.exe process from taskmanager

Comment: So, you want to detect when browser is being closed by user manually? and close IEDriverServer.exe from task manager. Is that right?

Comment: yep. thats what i m trying to achieve. Please help

Comment: Edited my earlier response. Please have a look!

Comment: that didnt work.still iexplorerdriver exe running in background process

Comment: Do you have a copy of exception messages that you are receiving when browser is closed manually BUT selenium code still running?

Comment: Don't think we are on the same page!!! Do you close browser manually in between the script execution? If yes, it will surely throw exception Or else if you are closing browser manually after all the scripts finished executing, you can write the kill process logic in tear down part! Is that understandable?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand. "Kill process logic in tear down part" when to add that logic/where is this part. please tell

Comment: Please clarify whether you are closing browser manually in between script execution or after script execution completes? To get ideas on tear down logic see this : http://202.201.18.40:8080/members/1000007/JUnit/JUnit4%20in%2010%20Minutes/JUnit4%20in%2010%20minutes.htm

Comment: i m closing browser after script execution completes

Comment: Open Command Prompt and execute **taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe** command. This will close **IEDriverServer.exe** process from task manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS test, on **[TestCleanup]** or **[ClassCleanup]**
add the following:

```
foreach(var process in Process.GetProcess("IEDriverServer"))
{
  process.Kill();
}
```