# Cucumber picocontainer/SharedDriver doesn't handle browser instance properly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm using cucumber-jvm picocontainer to share selenium driver between classes. I have ShareDriver and WebDriverFactory class.

My problem is the following:
1. If I run 2 test cases, the driver/browser instance is closed after the first test case, new browser instance is created and run the second one. I would like to use only 1 browser instance and run the tests, then close it.

2. IEDriverServer.exe and one java.exe are stucked on task manager after the test, however the browser is closed. I need to kill them manually. Every run creates a new one from these tasks. I tried all ideas from stackoverflow, but none of them could solve this problem.

Thanks!

My SharedDriver class:

```
public class SharedDriver extends EventFiringWebDriver implements Startable {

    public SharedDriver() {
        super(WebDriverFactory.localInternetExplorerWebDriver());
    }

    @After
    public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
        try {
            byte[] screenshot = getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
        } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
            System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        quit();
    }
}
```

My WebDriverFactory class:

```
class WebDriverFactory {
    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/webDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    }

    static WebDriver localInternetExplorerWebDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/webDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
        //returnCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        return new InternetExplorerDriver(returnCapabilities);
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation of SharedDriver is not correct. You need a static webdriver field in the shareddriver class, create a shutdown thread, add this thread to the jvm shutdown hook. Use this one - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java

Comment: I used that version before, but I assumed that the thread handling is not necessary. It seems, I was wrong :). However, using this example, the 2. point still exists, IEDriver and java are still stucked :/ Workaround can be just killing the processes (WindowsUtils) but I think it is not the best solution...

Comment: Are you getting a new IEDriver and java for each run which remains? Or  one process in the background? If you wanna kill that too use this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652692/how-to-kill-iedriver-exe-process-running-in-background-selenium-webdriver.... Add this to the shutdown hook

Comment: Btw IEDriver are real pain to work with. Too many workarounds and settings...

Comment: The only supported browser, I have to use it. Yes, I'm getting new IEDriver for each run and remains. Sometimes I collect 20 IEDriver and kill it from command prompt... Java.exe is different, only one remains.

Comment: Is it latest version? Guess Killing it in the shutdown hook would be the way.

Comment: Yes it is the latest version. Yeah, I spent lots of time to solve it, I will go for it. In the static method, Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(CLOSE_THREAD); should contains it am I correct?

Comment: Add it inside the run method of the thread after call to REAL_DRIVER.quit().

Comment: You helped with it a lot! Finally works with the example SharedDriver! Thank you!!! Please write the solution as an answer then I accept it! It can be helpful for others as well who struggling with SharedDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of SharedDriver is not correct. You need a static webdriver field in the shareddriver class, create a shutdown thread, add this thread to the jvm shutdown hook. Use this [one](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java)

If you wanna kill that too use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652692/how-to-kill-iedriver-exe-process-running-in-background-selenium-webdriver). Add this to the shutdown hook.Add it inside the run method of the thread after call to REAL_DRIVER.quit().

Comment: Let me add this: in run() method, REAL_DRIVER.close() doesn't quit and IEDriver remains in task manager. I could solve it to add REAL_DRIVER.quit(). Thanks Grasshopper!